# MongoDB query for update

Tags: mongodb

> db.tasks.find({user:"saturngod"});

is return

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4de20ef97065cc77c80541fd"),
 "todo" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "desc" : "hi",
        "done" : 0
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "desc" : "hello",
        "done" : 0
    }
], "user" : "saturngod" }
```

I want to update done = 1 when todo.id=1

So, I wrote

```
>db.tasks.update({'todo.id':1},{"$set":{todo:{done:1}}});
```

I lost all todo and only set done : 1

> db.tasks.find();

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4de20ef97065cc77c80541fd"), "todo" : { "done" : 1 }, "user" : "saturngod" }
```

How to update the value ? I want to do like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4de20ef97065cc77c80541fd"),
 "todo" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "desc" : "hi",
        "done" : 1
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "desc" : "hello",
        "done" : 0
    }
], "user" : "saturngod" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

got it.

```
db.tasks.update({'todo.id':1},{"$set":{"todo.$.done":1}});
```